# Array type variable changes to string on setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

How can I get the state and array to work consistently?

The results are so confusing and inconsistent.

This is state:

```
 this.state = {
            tutorSubjects: [],

        };
```

This is setting state; the first console.log logs the subject in an array, the second logs and empty array:

```
            const name = target.name;
            if (name === "tutorSubjects") {
                let subjects = this.state.tutorSubjects.concat(value);
                console.log(subjects)
                this.setState({
                    tutorSubjects: subjects
                },  console.log(this.state.tutorSubjects))
            }
```

this handles submit and logs th subject as a **string** without the array:

```
    handleSubmit = e => {
        console.log(this.state.tutorSubjects)
}
```

My main goal is to send an array to the server, and now it's sending a string.

I have not idea why, but now that I have changed the state to `subjects` and updated state like below, It works perfectly.

```
            if (name === "tutorSubjects") {
                let subjects = this.state.subjects.concat(value);
                console.log(subjects)
                this.setState({
                    subjects
                }, console.log(this.state.subjects))
            }
```

Comment: Could you please post separate working solution so that everyone knows this question has been resolved.

Comment: My question is still why did it work so wired

Answer (score 1):

The callback argument to [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) should be a *callback function* but you're not supplying it that way, instead you're evaluating `console.log(...)` immediately and displaying that *before* `setState` gets called.

Fix it by ensuring it runs *after*:

```
this.setState({ subjects }, () => console.log(this.state.subjects));
```

Your original code is roughly equivalent to:

```
let v = console.log(this.state.subjects);
this.setState({ subjects }, v);
```

Where clearly that's out of order when expressed that way.